# Using MFC Csocket on azure website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dll, azure-web-app-service, unmanaged

I'am developing web API app in azure website and i try  calling to unmanaged dll (c++) that use Csoket.

Is anybody know if azure website support using Csocket or maybe i need to replace it with web socket?

My error that get is "Unable to load dll (module not be found HRESULT: 0x8007007E)?

Comment: I would guess that the site does not have MFC runtime installed?

Comment: I can install mfc runtime at azure website?

Comment: Sombody know if winsock work on azure?

Comment: can you create and share a sample app that use Csocket? so that we can try to and debug?